# Python error, cannot import name Imputer on Spark ( Bluemix )

Tags: python, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, spyder

I have a problem I wrote my script on spark and when I run the script I have a problem of import but I don't understand why because when I run the same script in local via spyder, I don't get this error.
so why did I get this error? Is it Bluemix which has a problem?

Script:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
```

and my error is :

```
<ipython-input-2-13d49864f8d7> in <module>()
     66 from sklearn import preprocessing
     67 #from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
---> 68 from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


ImportError: cannot import name roc_auc_score

or 

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
      4 import sklearn.preprocessing as p
----> 5 from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
      6 #import sklearn.metrics as sm
      7 from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

ImportError: cannot import name Impute
```

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to install a newer version of `scikit-learn` in the user site-packages and import that one instead of `scikit-learn 0.11` from the system site-packages.

1.) Install newer version of `scikit-learn` (ignore the output "Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.11"):

```
!pip install --user --upgrade scikit-learn
```

2.) Display user name:

```
!whoami
```

3.) Set the path to user site-packages in front of the paths to system site-packages. Use the user name from step 2 for the variable USER_NAME:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/gpfs/fs01/user/USER_NAME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

4.) Check the `scikit-learn` version:

```
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__
```

The following code should run after the previous steps:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
```

After a restart of the kernel, step 3 has to be performed again in order to import the newer version of `scikit-learn` from the user site-packages!

Comment: thank for your answer. But I do all your recommendations and I still got the same error because when I enter this code "import sklearn sklearn.__version__  "  I get this '0.11'. So the update is unsuccessful

Comment: Did you try it in a new Python notebook, or in the same notebook in which you may have computed previously code involving the old package ? In the latter case you have to restart the kernel to clear environment. I will try the workaround again, but it was working for me.

Comment: I applied the workaround again and it is working for me. If you like, you can share the notebook with Bluemix Support, then I can have closer look.

Answer (score 1):

scikit_learn's version `0.11`, which is pre-installed in Bluemix notebooks does not have `Imputer` in `preprocessing`. Hence the `ImportError`.

In a Bluemix notebook, you can find the version of the library from the right-hand-side bar in the `Environment` tab.

Comment: Agreed with @Philipp Langer and the Imputer is introduced in later verrsion.
One of the way to upgrade is but interestingly Pip on Bluemix is installing the older version.
`!pip install --user --upgrade scikit-learn==0.17.1`

You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting scikit-learn==0.17.1
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.17.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.11

Answer (score 1):

So I had to use,

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

instead of

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
```

Otherwise, it gives the following error.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
ImportError: cannot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'
```

Answer (score 0):

In juypter notebook, it's working fine

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer 
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```